# how to solve code 10, message 10: with google signing option

Tags: firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1oCl.jpg)

Hello guys, i just created my first app, and when emulated worked perfectly, but when i build the apk release file, i get this toast code 10, message 10:, i know there are the same questions but and i have tried to solve the problem using the solutions in previos posts, but no result, i have changed the SHA1 many times, donloaded json files many times, re installed the app, and erased the google account, none of that worked, the issue is only with google signing option, whe using the email option it works fine, i am using 
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [app signing by Google Play](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#app-signing-google-play), you need to make sure that you add the SHA-1 fingerprint from the Google Play Console to your list of Firebase fingerprints.

After you have uploaded your app to the Play Store, go to your Google Play Console, select your app, and under Release Management, select App signing:
[image]

On that screen, you can find the SHA-1 fingerprint in the "App signing key certificate" section. Copy and paste that into your Firebase fingerprints (Firebase Console -> Project -> General Settings).

Once you add it, it may take a few minutes to take effect but this fixed the issue for me.

Comment: thanks a lot! that was the solution to the problem.